# PHP generate POST form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I generate a form based on some data I get from a database.

Here is my constructor:

php_core.php

```
<?php
    echo "<style>";
    echo ".spoll{ -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;";
    echo "-moz-box-sizing: border-box;";
    echo "box-sizing: border-box;";
    echo "padding: 10px;";
    echo "padding-top: 5px;";
    echo "}";
    echo "</style>";

    //DISPLAY FUNCTION

    function display($x){
        require("db_conx.php");
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM polls WHERE id='$x' LIMIT 1";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            $poll_id = $row['id'];
            $topic = $row['topic'];
            $startdate = $row['startdate'];
            $stopdate = $row['stopdate'];
            $active = $row['active'];
            $type = $row['type'];
            $title = $row['title'];
            $pwidth = $row['pwidth'];
            $borcolor = $row['borcolor'];
            $borwidth = $row['borwidth'];
            $fcolor = $row['fcolor'];
            $bfcol = $row['bfcol'];
            $bg = $row['bg'];
            $borrad = $row['borrad'];
            $abars = $row['abars'];
            $bcol = $row['bcol'];
            $brad = $row['brad'];

        }

            //DISPLAY THE POLL
            $aquery = "SELECT * FROM answers WHERE parent='$poll_id'";
            $result = mysqli_query($db_conx, $aquery);
            echo '<div class="spoll" style="width: '.$pwidth.'px; border: '.$borwidth.'px solid '.$borcolor.'; border-radius: '.$borrad.'px; color: '.$fcolor.'; background-color: '.$bg.';">';
            echo '<p><b>'.$title.'</b></p>';
            echo '<p style="font-size: 13px;">'.$topic.'</p>';
            echo '<form method="post" action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'">';

            // SELECT ANSWERS
            if($type == 'single'){
                while ($usersRow = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                    echo '<input type="radio" name="rad" value="'.$usersRow['id'].'"/>'.$usersRow['content'].'<br><br>';
                }
            } else {
                $i = 0;
                while ($usersRow = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="'.$usersRow['id'].'"/>'.$usersRow['content'].'<br><br>';
                    $i++;
                }
            }

            //echo '<button style="border-radius: '.$brad.'px; border: none; padding: 10px; width: 100%; margin: auto; background-color: '.$bcol.'; color:'.$bfcol.'" value="VOTE" onclick="vote('.$poll_id.');"><b>VOTE</b></button>';
            echo '<input type="submit" value="Vote" style="border-radius: '.$brad.'px; border: none; padding: 10px; width: 100%; margin: auto; background-color: '.$bcol.'; color:'.$bfcol.'">';
            echo '</form>';
            echo '</div>';
    }

    // END OF THE DISPLAY FUNCTION


?>
```

Here is how I display the form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<?php include("php_includes/php_core.php"); ?>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php display('15'); ?>
<span id="status"></span>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
echo "Posted!";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know why, but it won't submit the values! The function outputs the form correctly, I've checked it by viewing the page source. I have no idea why it does not work, so I need your help. I've been modifying the script again and again, no result.

An additional(optional) question about this script:
Do you have any idea about how I can submit this form using AJAX without any additional HTML tags and refresh the function output without reloading the page? I found some ways, but I must wrap the function inside a div and I need to keep the output structure and method, so I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a `name` attribute to your submit button.

`<input type="submit" value="Vote">`

should be

`<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Vote">`

You are checking if `$_POST['submit']` exists when it doesn't.

For the additional question, I would recommend using `jQuery's` Ajax function. [See here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Yep, it was that simple. I can't believe it. Thank you! Do you have any idea about that optional question?

Comment: @Sergiu Look into using `jQuery`. See my updated post, I have linked directly to the function you would use.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't submit the form because you have not set any `name` to the button.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

}
```

`submit` doesn't exists.

Change to:

```
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit">';
```

Comment: Oh my god! I can't believe it. I've spent 2+ hours looking for what was wrong. I cant believe it was that simple! Thank you, man! Do you have any idea about the optional question?

Comment: Yes, I do, but I can't answer since it's a whole different topic :p

Comment: I can't post another question. It's asking me to edit this question because it's too soon to ask something again...

Comment: What you're trying to achieve is easy, you need to take a look at the documentation http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/